# assigning mock functions on `import *` with flowjs

Tags: javascript, types, mocking, flowtype, covariant

Say I have the following code:

```
export const exampleFunc = () => {}
```

Which is then used in a test like so:

```
import * as exampleAll from '../../path/to/example'


describe('Example', () => {

  exampleAll.exampleFunc = jest.fn()
})
```

This fails to typecheck with:

Cannot assign jest.fn() to exampleAll.exampleFunc because property exampleFunc is not writable.

```
 44│ const mockStore = configureStore([reduxThunk])
 45│
 46│ describe('[Redux action] ExampleAction()', () => {
 47│     exampleAll.exampleFunc = jest.fn()
 48│     beforeEach(() => {
 49│       exampleAll.exampleFunc.mockReturnValue(() => () => {})
 50│     })
```

Why is it not writable? And how can I do such mocking while also using flow?

Thanks!

Comment: I think imports are treated as read only.  You could copy the import to another object, `const testExamples = { ...exampleAll, exampleFunc: jest.fn() };`

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not solve the problem. The function `exampleFunc` of the `exampleAll` module is not mocked sucessfully

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Ultimately I just stopped typechecking my tests. But I'd love to hear if somebody comes up with a solution!

Comment: Could you spy on the function with `jest.spyOn(exampleAll, 'exampleFunc')`? https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname